# Which text editors for iPhone support tabs and editing files in Dropbox in-place?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, dropbox, text-editor

I've been searching for a text editor on iPhone with the following features:

- Support for browsing files in Dropbox and editing them in-place.
- Support for keeping more than one file open at a time and switching between them.

Apps that don't meet my requirements:

- GoodReader supports tabs, but it doesn't allow me to edit files in-place in Dropbox.
- Byword allows me to edit files in Dropbox in-place, but it doesn't have tabs.

Are there any iPhone apps that support tabs and editing files in Dropbox in-place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[GoCoEdit](http://gocoedit.com)**

GoCoEdit is a Code and Text Editor optimized for fast opening and editing local (on iOS device) and remote (on server) files with your iOS Device.

It supports extended syntax highlighting on many coding languages and has a themable interface with many dark and light themes.

**Features:**

> - Universal App (use it on your iPad, iPhone & iPod Touch)
> - Connect to your servers via SFTP, FTP, Google Drive, Dropbox or OneDrive
> - Multiple Tabs
> - Very fast reconnect and recover of open files after restart
> - Upload and Download files/folders or edit files directly on your server/dropbox/drive without download
> - Supporting iOS9 features like textselection by cursor, Splitview and Slide-Over
> - Supporting 3D Touch
> - External/Bluetooth keyboard support, with lots of shortcuts

Answer (score -1):

Textastic 3 is awesome and has tab/dropbox support